# Has community user gone postal?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, serverfault, community-user

I can't see any good reason why Community has bumped so many questions. There's been no anonymous edits, retags, etc.

[image]

And I notice here on MSO a whole bunch of [community](/questions/tagged/community) questions has been recently updated, so I'm wondering if something's gone wrong, or am I just missing something?

They have all just had some spam destroyed, but in the past this hasn't involved bumping, has it?

Comment: [Cultural decode](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_postal#Verb)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that going postal is a cultural thing (or maybe I just watch too many American movies)

Comment: Probably related to [this change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/community-should-discriminate-more-when-bumping-unanswered-questions/99690#99690) somehow.

Comment: The community user randomly bumps old questions that have not been answered anyway. So this is not really unusual.

Comment: @Cody - is it meant to bump 6 questions at seemingly random time intervals?

Comment: Why not? The random time intervals don't seem strange to me at all. Are you concerned about the *quantity*? Six seems like too many to bump at one time with no other activity in between?

Comment: @cody - yeah, the number is unusual, but also the time spans. They were bumped at 2,2,3,3,1,14 minutes apart

Comment: Given my last name, I resemble that remark. Of all of the synonyms available for bat **** crazy, you _had_ to pick that one :P

Comment: Oh no! It's Skynet all over again!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On Server Fault, there was a spam account that had answered 5 out of the 6 questions in your screenshot, which triggered the bumping.

The account's deletion caused Community to show up as the last activity user.

Evil spammers!