# Is this a bug? Did "Community" do anything to this question?

Tags: discussion, community-user

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)

I found this question shown on the "active" list, as in the following picture:

[image]

But I went though carefully on [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85399/bug-deleting-a-negative-ranked-question-or-answer-or-comment-votes-disappear), none of the operations was done by "Community".

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, this is not a bug.**

The Community user automatically bumps "old", [unanswered](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/) questions to get them some attention.

This is confirmed by the "about me" section in the [Community user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community):

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep Stack Overflow clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted

Comment: Good idea. But I think change "randomly" poke old unanswered questions into "select" the old question that earned high upvote is better.

Comment: @Roy: But that misses the point. We want to bump questions that *don't* have any answers so that we can *get them answered*. There's no reason to bump or poke questions that already have answers with lots of upvotes.

Comment: I mean "select" the old question that earned high upvote in unanswered questions, at least add more "random" weight to the more upvotes question.

Comment: @Roy: The algorithm has been tweaked a bit recently. See this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/community-should-discriminate-more-when-bumping-unanswered-questions