# Policy to make old Questions visible

Tags: discussion, feature-request, old-questions

I know that answering an old question will bring it back to front on the SO site.

Nevertheless I am not aware if there already is (but I think it would be important to have) some kind of policy for bringing questions back to top in a regular way, in order to avoid starvation for old ones.

Some good questions may have been asked while experts of related topics were not active, or in really unlucky time periods and have not received the amount of attention they deserved.

Of course any kind of implemented policy for old questions revival shouldn't draw too much attention away from new and hot questions.

A possible way of doing it could be to assign each question a hotness rate, that decreases with time but is busted up once in a while, or if someone answers the question (how is already happening).

Any thoughts about this idea?

Comment: I think [Community](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) occasionally bumps old questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature you describe already exists. Old, [unanswered](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/) questions are periodically "bumped" by the [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user. This is confirmed by its profile, which says:

> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention

This causes the questions to appear on the front page of the site, just as if a new answer had been posted and/or the question had been edited.

The algorithm it uses to determine which questions should be bumped [was tweaked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99690/153008) recently. It now...

> favors unanswered questions with lots of views. Right now it takes the top 100 unanswered questions with no recent activity by views, then picks randomly from within that group.

Comment: thks for clearing my doubts! ;D