# Unanswered Questions without any activity

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

If someone has asked a question on any stack exchange website and the question remains unanswered for a long time i.e. no one has answered/commented on that question. Should there be an option to get your question again in the latest list of questions (just once maybe)?

Comment: There already [are such options](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions). You can [place a bounty on it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). From time to time old unanswered questions might get an automatic bump. And if you improve/update your question, it will get bumped as well.

Comment: If someone has not gothigh reputation, then bounty can't be used. And is there any criteria for automatic bumping?

Comment: A rep of 75 should not be that difficult to reach. And as I said, then there is still the (entirely free) option of improving your question.

Comment: yeah... Improving your question is a good way... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already in place - the system itself is auto bumping questions with no accepted or upvoted answers after certain amount of time.

It's done through the [Community user account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community). I couldn't find the official statement about this mechanism but it's explained pretty well in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/community-should-discriminate-more-when-bumping-unanswered-questions) here on Meta with [Jeff answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99690/152859) giving some technical details as well:

> Just to be 100% clear, **our definition of unanswered is "no upvoted answers".**
>
> I recently tweaked the community bumping so that it favors unanswered questions with lots of views. Right now **it takes the top 100 unanswered questions with no recent activity by views, then picks randomly from within that group**.

I think it's done after two months of inactivity (no new answer or edit) and when question got answer with upvote it won't get auto bumped.