# Questions asked during low hours: Randomly replay during peak hours

Tags: feature-request, homepage

To old users it might be somewhat obvious what time and day to ask questions. Not so much to some new users though.

Would it make sense to replay the questions that didn't get much of front-page views as much as others?

Answer (score 15):

What would you consider to be insufficiently viewed?

That aside, wouldn't doing that create a self-perpetuating cycle of replays since bumping older questions would get in the way of new questions getting front page time? (Especially on Stack Overflow where there's a steady stream of questions at all times.)

And in addition to *that*, people arrive at questions through various means - some look at the front page, some look at specific tags, some follow feeds, etc. Front page views aren't necessarily all that meaningful, although it probably depends on the site.

In other words, I think this request needs more research, details, and analysis of pros and cons.

Answer (score 8):

If a question is asked during low-volume hours, doesn't that mean that there's less stuff coming in to push that question off the front page?  It seems plausible that the questions that run the most risk of being lost are the ones that come in during the *high*-volume hours, when churn is greatest.

Also, Community♦ regularly bumps older unanswered questions, so we already have something to address the problem you're raising.

Comment: Community bumps only questions with an answer, so it's no help to those that were completely overlooked. Agree with the rest.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato [Community bumps questions with no upvoted answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99690/162102).  "No answers" is a subset of that.  I've definitely seen bumps of questions with no answers.

Comment: The rules for bumping are [documented here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/). A question may appear to be bumped by Community when it was in fact bumped by a spam/offensive post by a user that was subsequently destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  That doesn't match my experience; I'm pretty sure I've seen truly-unanswered questions get bumped, on sites where I can see deleted posts and it's not the spam/offensive case.  It's possible that things have changed since that post was written.  I left a comment there asking about it.