# Excavator badge awarded for editing question after Community♦ had bumped it to the home page

Tags: support, community-user, bump, edit-badges

I just received an [Excavator badge](https://serverfault.com/help/badges/155/excavator?userid=178024) for [Why can't I access my FTP server with Windows Explorer?](https://serverfault.com/questions/943361/why-cant-i-access-my-ftp-server-with-windows-explorer).

[image: received Excavator for "Why can't I access my FTP server with Windows Explorer?"]

However, I was just *browsing the home page*, not merely looking for old posts; this question appeared like this (it's a different site, but you get the idea):

[image]

The question detail was like this:

[image]

My point is, it was the Community♦ user who "excavated" this question, not me. I was just browsing the home page feed, there was no "excavation" from my side.

If this is a bug or feature, I don't know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bump by the Community user doesn't influence whether a post is eligible for the Excavator badge; only the timestamp of the last edit (or in this case, the original post) does. That was December 2018, more than 6 months ago, so you're eligible for the badge.

The bump by the Community user was a good reason to edit the question; it's even mentioned as [one of the benefits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99690/295232). The badge wasn't introduced for cases like this (the badge has a period of 180 days, while for the bumping it's [30 days or more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/295232)) but you can consider it to be just a nice bonus.