# Too much flags waiting for review: should I stop flagging a moment?

Tags: support, flags

Please do not flag this question as a duplicate of this one: [Should I worry about flagging too much?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88104/should-i-worry-about-flagging-too-much) This is not a *general* question, but more a localized question that probably should be closed as soon as replied.

These days, I sent a lot of flag. I noticed that more I send flag, more I can send flag. I can currently flag 62 times per day and all the flags all can't be reviewed quickly. So the number of flag waiting for review is growing, growing, and growing.

I have currently more than a hundred flags waiting for review and I don't know if it is a problem. So please just let me know If I should stop a moment?

Note: my goal is just to participate to maintain quality of the site. It is not to break the machine. ;-)

Comment: Just keep flagging. Not all flags go to moderators. And it might take the community a while to get to it. Don't worry. If there is something wrong, just flag.

Comment: @Bart Thanks for your comment. I wondering if there is a technical limit to not exceed or something like this. I was afraid to break the machine. :)

Comment: I'm sure they're using `long int` to store their flag count.

Comment: If flagging more than a certain number of times broke stack exchange then that is very much stack exchange's problem

Comment: In case you do end up breaking something: http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/

Comment: @Chris, this question is not really localized. (You phrased it in a way specific to you, but the problem of "is this too much flagging" is a general one). Also, this is not a dupe -- that other question was basically "I am doing so much flagging that I'm unsure if I'm flagging appropriately" whereas your question is more like "I'm doing so much flagging that I'm unsure if this is too much for the system or community to handle".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, don't stop flagging. If your flags are consistently getting approved, then you are good at flagging and should continue to do so. If there are a hundred of your flags waiting to be reviewed, so be it.

It's not just the diamond moderators that handle flags. Community members with at least 10,000 reputation have access to [Moderator Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). This tool set is a lot more limited than that of diamond moderators, but it does include this:

> Handle flags on posts when they ask for a question to be closed or a post to be deleted

I see that you have less than 3,000 rep so you don't have the [Cast Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege, so a significant portion of your flags are probably of this form. The community has a lot of 10k rep users, and they generally do a good job of keeping this queue down.

I can't speak for the workload of diamond moderators, but they should be able to keep up with your flagging volume. If they can't, it's not really your problem -- you should keep sending good flags, and the site could use an additional moderator.

As far as the Stack Exchange system itself, I'd be really surprised if it can't handle your flag volume, and on the off-chance that it can't, that would be a pretty big bug and also not your problem.

Comment: I though close flags went into the > 3k close queue

Comment: @RichardTingle, I'm pretty sure that's just close votes, not close flags. Look at the moderator tools privilege page and scroll down. You'll see screenshots of close flags in the queue.

Comment: @BenLee Your interpretation does seem fair. But equally from the [close vote privilege](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions); "Any post which currently has an active close vote or a canonical flag reason identical to a close vote will appear in the Close Votes review queue. "

Comment: @RichardTingle, good catch. I guess it goes into both.

Comment: There are definitely things in the Close Votes review queue that have no close votes but do have flags. (And the community doesn't particularly do a good job keeping up with these, unfortunately.)